# Javascript popup and close

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Crew</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.page-popup {
    z-index:500;
    position:absolute;
    left:345px;
    background:#fff;
    width:680px;
    height:325px;
    top:175px;
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.first').click(function() {
    var onOff=false;

    if (onOff=false) {  
        $('.page-popup').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete
        });
        onOff = true;
    } else {
        $('.page-popup').fadeOut('slow', function() {

        }); 
        onOff = false;
    }
});
```

I am trying to create an open close popup effect. When they click on the link the popup fades in, when I click on the link again the popup fades out.

*UPDATED. I have figured out how to make it work. I must place the declare:

```
var onOff=false;
```

at page load not when the onclick is executing otherwise it always resets it.......and of course using == for comparison :)

Comment: one error if (onOff=false) should be if (onOff==false). Its comparison operator

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post it as an answer below and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is incorrect `if (onOff=false)`. It should be `if (onOff==false)`

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: Yes that was one major problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Splatty, Great. If this answer solved your issue, please accept it as your answer. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

As other users already mentioned, you must correct your condition to if (onOff==false)
also you might want to prevent the default event handler on the click from executing. Change your code to

```
$('.first').click(function(event) {
    event.preventdefault();
    //rest of the code
}
```

This will prevent unnecessary scrolling of the page.